# Excel formula needed call data from different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to formula a cell
Exp When cell A1 data is S001, then B1 Cell will Show E2 Data.
When cell A2 data is S002, then B2 Cell will show F4 Data.

A column is variable, B column need a formula to call data to show up.

Please help

Comment: please consider improving your question.

Comment: Check out [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then come back and edit your question so it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an IF function?

`=if(A2="S002",F4)`

^put this in B2

By the way, you should probably post your attempt thus far before asking for code, it's a very obvious formula, unless you are completely new in which case you should read up on Excel before asking the community.